# How to Add rows to a table based on the number input from a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am new to VBA and while I can typically search out an answer for what I am looking for, I have not been able to find anything for the scenario I need that works. 
Scenario: I have a workbook where “Total Locations” will have a number placed in cell H3. This placement will not change, Only the number/data to reflect how many total locations there are will change. (If there are 10 locations, 10 will be input in H3, if 5 locations exist, 5 will be input in H3 instead.)

I have a table for “Scheduled Milestone Activities” elsewhere on the sheet. What I want to achieve is to add rows to this table based on the number input into the Total columns cell (H3). If 10 is input into H3 the table should have 10 rows, if 20 locations = 20 rows, etc.

The default placement for the table is A46:L46 for the headers. The Rows I need added would exist starting with row 47 and based on the input in H3 and rows would be added based on that input.

Some challenges to me figuring this out also include the fact that there is other data that may change the default location of this table. The columns would not change (A:L) but it may begin on a different row if/when rows are added to other tables above this one.

Removing rows may also need to factor in, if possible, but just adding rows would suffic[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHbA8.png)e. The ultimate desired result is to have the row count in this table match the number input into H3. H3=1: Table has one row, H3=2: Table has 2 rows, H3=3: Table has 3 rows, and so on.

Can this be done? With or without a macro?

2 images attached.

Thanks in advance!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBSRm.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your table is formatted as an Excel Table, it will make this much easier. The table can then be referred to by name and it won't matter if it moves onto a different row. So, if you haven't done that already, put your cursor in the table and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

In my example, I've named the table LocationTable.

I created a couple of cells to control the behavior of the macro.

H3 is named location_table_size.

H4 is named clear_table_before_add.

Naming cells is useful in case they need to be moved.

I start with this:

[image]

I created this macro:

```
Public Sub InsertRow()

Dim thisTable As ListObject
Dim thisRow As ListRow
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim clear_first As Boolean

Set thisTable = Range("LocationTable").ListObject

' get the flag whether to clear the table first or not
clear_first = Sheet1.Range(Names("clear_table_before_add").RefersTo)

If clear_first = True And thisTable.ListRows.Count > 0 Then

    Debug.Print 'Clearing LocationTable'
    thisTable.DataBodyRange.Delete

End If

' get the number of rows to add
j = Sheet1.Range(Names("location_table_size").RefersTo)

Debug.Print "Inserting " & j & " rows to LocationTable"

For i = 1 To j

    Debug.Print "..." & i

    Set thisRow = thisTable.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)

    thisRow.Range.Cells(1, 1) = i

Next i

End Sub
```

Basically, it will add however many rows are mentioned in the cell named location_table_size. In retrospect it should've been called rows_to_add, but oh well!

If clear_table_before_add is TRUE, then it will remove any rows in there before adding the new rows. If it's FALSE, then it won't.

To make the whole thing more robust, put some data validation on those cells to make sure you can only put positive numbers in the first cell and TRUE/FALSE in the second.

After running it, it looks like this:

[image]